# Access Select Max date with corresponding records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a query that looks at the most recent date and return the corresponding values. Using the `max` function works only if I have the `hose part no` and `max inspection` columns and nothing else. Once I add in the `scrap amount` columns it duplicates the `hose part no` column. I only want one single record per hose part no.

Below is an example of what is going on:

`Hose Part No Max Inspection Date scrapamt1 scrapamt2  scrapamt3 scrapamt4`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does `NewScrapTble` and `tblReleaseNo` link up.  The image is only showing one table.  What do you want to happen to `scrapamt2 - 4` when it combines the multiple records into one?

Comment: I have the tables setup through a relationship where the primary key is the release number. The image is a query result. What I want the hose part no with the most recent record with the scrap amount for that day. Here is an example                                                                                                          Hose Part No MaxOfInspect Date   scrapamnt1
2807-10                    5/23/2017             60
2807-12                   6/16/2017              12
2807-12T                   1/13/2017               80
2807-20                  11/27/2017             1

Comment: So `scrapamt1` for `2807-12T` on the `01/13/2017` would be `130` - i.e. `120+10`.  Can you show us the design of the two tables - at the moment you're only showing us the result of your query which doesn't help much - unless you'd mentioned it I would've just said group your non-calculated fields.

Comment: You can edit extra information into your question by using the _Edit_ button just under the tags.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the data as it appears in both tables. I'm suprised that `Release No` is the PK in both tables - indicates that both tables could have been combined.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, this is what you want:

```
Select * From Table1 Inner Join
(Select Table1.[Hose Part No], Max(Table1.[Max Inspection Date]) As [MaxOfMax Inspection Date] From Table1 Group By Table1.[Hose Part No]) As MaxValues
On Table1.[Hose Part No] = MaxValues.[Hose Part No] And Table1.[Max Inspection Date] = MaxValues.[MaxOfMax Inspection Date]
```

A subquery (named `MaxValues`) is used to determine the maximum `Max Inspection Date` per `Hose Part No` and will be joined to the same table.

Because you also didn't mention the table Name, I choosed `Table1`.

Comment: I apologize. The inspection date and scrap amounts is from table NewScrapTble and the Hose Part No is from tblReleaseNo

Comment: And the screenshot is the result of a query? Please show the exact design of both tables.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a screen shot in this comment section. sorry I am new to this page.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working -

**tblReleaseNo:**

```
| Release No | Hose Part No | Release Date | Due Date   |
|------------|--------------|--------------|------------|
| 1          | Hose 1       | 01/01/2018   | 01/01/2018 |
| 2          | Hose 1       | 01/01/2018   | 01/01/2018 |
| 3          | Hose 2       | 01/01/2018   | 01/01/2018 |
| 4          | Hose 2       | 01/01/2018   | 01/01/2018 |
| 5          | Hose 3       | 01/01/2018   | 01/01/2018 |
```

**NewScrapTble:**

```
| Release No | Inspect Date | scrapamt1 | reason1 | scrapamt2 |
|------------|--------------|-----------|---------|-----------|
| 1          | 01/12/2018   | 10        |         | 15        |
| 2          | 12/12/2018   | 15        |         | 18        |
| 3          | 01/07/2018   | 12        |         | 12        |
| 4          | 01/08/2018   | 14        |         | 200       |
| 5          | 01/03/2017   | 22        |         | 20        |
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  [Hose Part No]
        , MAX([Inspect Date]) AS Inspect
        , LAST(scrapamt1) AS Amount1
        , LAST(scrapamt2) AS Amount2
FROM    (
        SELECT  [Hose Part No]
                , [Inspect Date]
                , scrapamt1
                , scrapamt2
        FROM    tblReleaseNo INNER JOIN NewScrapTble ON 
                    tblReleaseNo.[Release No] = NewScrapTble.[Release No]
        )
GROUP BY [Hose Part No]
```

**Final Table:**

```
| Hose Part No | Inspect    | Amount1 | Amount2 |
|--------------|------------|---------|---------|
| Hose 1       | 12/12/2018 | 15      | 18      |
| Hose 2       | 01/08/2018 | 14      | 200     |
| Hose 3       | 01/03/2017 | 22      | 20      |
```

*Note:*  I'm not 100% sure that `LAST` is correct, it is pulling the correct amounts but not sure if it will trip up on some records?

Comment: I tried it but, for some reason its not pulling the correct amounts.

Comment: You're going to get annoyed in a minute - could you paste the data table as a table I can copy from please rather than an image so I can test with your data.  This [link](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) provides a quick way to format tables - just paste them into your question and format as code.

Comment: The `Release No` values are different in the two screen shots so it won't be pulling anything - it's using them to link the two tables together.

Comment: Saying that when I update the `Release No` so I do get figures back - you're right, it is returning the incorrect scrap amount.  You've also got multiple scrap amounts for the same day making multiple records the most recent date - what do you want to happen there?