# SQL Find most recent record for each unique ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access, wanting to query each unique record ID based on most recent date and a third condition where another column of record ID score is less than 60

Sample table:

| RecordID | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 60 | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | 80 | 1/1/2020 |
| 2 | 60 | 1/1/2021 |

Query would pull:

| RecordID | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | 60 | 1/1/2021 |

I initially tried to just pull the Record ID & the most recent date as a starting point:

```
SELECT RecordID, MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY RecordID;
```

But all it does is return me

| RecordID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| null | 1/1/2021 |

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Comment: The query you show should not have returned that. It should have returned the desired result without the `Score` column.

Comment: If you want values *less than 60*, why is `60` in the result set?  Also, your sample data cannot return `NULL` for the `RecordId` for a simple aggregation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Select Max date with corresponding records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227071/access-select-max-date-with-corresponding-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Score 60s to appear on your query result, the criteria must be Less than or equal to 60.
and then the code is:

```
SELECT Table.RecordID, Table.Score, Max(Table.Date) AS MaxDate
FROM [Table]
WHERE (((Table.Score)<=60))
GROUP BY Table.RecordID, Table.Score;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My initial query didn't work because my RecordID call differed from my dataset header x.x